# jsyaml safeDump typescript support

Tags: javascript, typescript, js-yaml

I am trying to use jsymal.safeDump(somedata). I have run

```
npm install --save-dev @types/js-yaml
```

Also have my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "js-yaml"
    ]
  },
}
```

But whenever I use jsyaml.safeDump it shows
`Property 'safeDump' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/myPath/node_modules/@types/js-yaml/index")`

It can be solved using @ts-ignore

But is there any other way I can use safeDump without ignoring typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `safeDump()` is deprecated from the `js-yaml` version 4.x. To use `safeDump()` with type seftey use the `js-yaml` version 3.x with supported type module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml/v/3.14.1